# Keyboard layout changes after login

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

In my system with Ubuntu 14.04 system, I've recognized that my keyboard layout changes after I log in. Normally I use **only** Turkish keyboard layout, I can use it during login screen appears but after that it turns back to English layout even regarding indicator shows "Tr", regarding to Turkish.

Each time I have to;

- remove Turkish layout
- add English layout (temporarily)
- add Turkish layout again
- remove English one

Could you tell me how can I fix it, what's the reason of the issue?

Comment: Next time, leave the EN layout where it is and log out after setting TR as default. (are you running your UI in English?)

Comment: @Fabby For now, I'm doing sth like you said, I now have two layouts for possible error. (UI lang is English of course)

Comment: So what happens after you log out and back in without deleting?  Is the English keyboard the default or the Turkish?

Comment: @Fabby Turkish layout is default, additional layout makes it fixed temporarily but it should be done without that.

Comment: Please keep it that way until we've gone to the bottom of this. What's the output of `set | grep ^L[A,C]` and the settings for system settings - language support - language (list all black ones)  and if you're around, go to chat, Ubuntu General room and shout for me there!
`